# The phone which is connected to the PC has crashed when I choose the mode "Transfer files"

Tags: android

I want to push something into my phone on `Android Oreo`,but when my phone is connected to the PC, I choose the mode `Transfer files`, it has crashed.here is my crashed log.

please see the log:

```
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.native_perf_hint(Native method)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.qualcomm.qti.Performance.perfHint(Performance.java:65)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.util.BoostFramework.perfHint(BoostFramework.java:176)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.addStorageLocked(MtpService.java:295)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.addStorageDevicesLocked(MtpService.java:67)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.manageServiceLocked(MtpService.java:214)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   - locked <0x0a63faea> (a java.lang.Class<com.android.providers.media.MtpService>)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.onStartCommand(MtpService.java:156)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap20(ActivityThread.java:-1)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1698)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6548)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
01-04 05:14:19.839  7537  7537 F zygote64: java_vm_ext.cc:504]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
01-04 05:14:19.930  7537  7537 F zygote64: runtime.cc:492] Runtime aborting...
```

Comment: Appreciate it in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem because the second parameter in function(BoostFramework.perfHint) is NULL.so use getApplicationContext().getPackageName() instead of null in MtpService.java,look at the below:

```
-mPerfBoost.perfHint(BoostFramework.VENDOR_HINT_MTP_BOOST,null,Integer.MAX_VALUE,-1);
+mPerfBoost.perfHint(BoostFramework.VENDOR_HINT_MTP_BOOST,getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),Integer.MAX_VALUE,-1);
```